# OS X gcc: How to include a different lib directory for #include <...> header?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, homebrew

I had some problem with the original Xcode standard lib . So I decided to install the gcc and openMPI from Homebrew. I followed several tips on how to install the gcc on OS X, such as:
    $rm /usr/bin/gcc
    $ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/g++5 gcc
etc. and export the new /.../5.3.0/bin and /.../5.3.0/lib to $PATH.

In the makefile, I used '-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include' option. However, I met the problem when I compiled the code:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/iostream:38:10: fatal error:
'bits/c++config.h' file not found

The problem happens because the iostream has the following:

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

I suppose the compiler knows the directory for searching the new . But the '#include ' in those standard lib is not working correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the right compiler?

Comment: What are your problems with Xcode standard lib?

Comment: The code is running fine on another ubuntu PC with gcc.  When I start with the Xcode standard lib. The error I got is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/valarray:977:50: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'value_type' (aka 'Field2D')
    void     resize(size_t __n, value_type __x = value_type()); @Jean-Baptiste Yunès

Comment: I remove the cc, gcc, g++, etc in /usr/bin. And substitute the link to the ones installed by Homebrew as I mentioned in the main thread. The "gcc -v" command gives me: Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Configured with:.... Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (Homebrew gcc 5.3.0) @Chiel

Comment: That means that the type you use to instanciate the `valarray` doesn't have a default ctor or a ctor callable with no parameter. I don't know why it works with Ubuntu, but this kind of error is "classical" with many collections structures.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks, My problem is indeed from the ctor. e.g., valarray< valarray<int> > matr(valarray<int>(3), 2) is fine with both compilers. But I try to call valarray<matrix1d> matr(matrix1d(3), 2), where class matrix1d{valarray<int> *v; matrix1d(int x){v = new valarray<int> (x);} ...}.  Then it will give me the above error related to resize() function built within std::valarray